# How to use a parameter from NodeLabelParameter Plugin with the "build" step of Jenkins Workflow

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a job that take a "Node" parameter provided by the NodeLabelParameter plugin, and I would like to call it from a jenkins "Workflow" job, via the "build" step.

When I use the Snippet Generator with "Build a job", the generated code is :

```
build job: 'test job', parameters: [<object of type org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.NodeParameterValue>]
```

Of course this is not valid.

I tried this (I found this constructor in the NodeLabelParameter plugin code):

```
build job: 'test job', parameters: [[new org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.NodeParameterValue('UPSTREAM_NODE', '', 'my_node')]]
```

But the build fails with this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep.parameters expects class hudson.model.ParameterValue but received class java.util.ArrayList
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.coerce(DescribableHelper.java:250)
...
```

What is the correct syntax to use such a parameter from a workflow job ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The exception is because you have an extraneous set of square brackets. Try

```
build job: 'test job', parameters: [new org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.NodeParameterValue('UPSTREAM_NODE', '', 'my_node')]
```

However the preferred syntax is something like

```
build job: 'test job', parameters: [[$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'UPSTREAM_NODE', labels: ['my_node'], nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
```

which is what I would expect the Snippet Generator to produce, assuming you are running Workflow version 1.3 or higher with [this fix](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/pull/69). If you are, and the Snippet Generator still fails to produce valid code, please file a bug report.

Comment: Your second syntax works like a charm, thanks, but the Snippet Generator produces `parameters: [<object of type org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.NodeParameterValue>]`. I am running jenkins 1.609 and workflow-plugin 1.5. Regards

Comment: File a bug for the Snippet Generator failure.

Comment: For the record, reported as [JENKINS-47571](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47571).