# Trigger Jenkins job on same node than parent with Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In a Jenkins job, I want to trigger another Jenkins job from a Groovy script :

```
other_job.scheduleBuild();
```

But other_job is not launched on the same node than the parent job. How can I modify my script to launch other_job on the same node than the parent job ?

I used to do that with the "Trigger/call builds on other project" and "NodeLabel Parameter" plugins but I would like now to do that inside a script.

[image]

Comment: Do you use a Jenkins pipeline, or just a Groovy script inside a freestyle job?

Comment: @biruk1230 I use a Groovy script inside a freestyle job

Comment: So, it's not working, when you're trying to run [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922333/10721592) code, yes?
Probably the issue is with node itself (there can be only one executor on that node - in that case jobs cannot run in parallel).

Comment: Also, as already said, please check `Restrict where this project can be run` option in 'other_job' configuration - you must specify the same node name there.

Comment: @biruk1230 No sorry, I can't test your answer now, I will tell you if it works in a few days.

Comment: @biruk1230 <quote>Also, as already said, please check Restrict where this project can be run option in other_job</quote>, so it means that I have to do that also in the "parent job" ? Otherwise how can I know the node name ? It would be better to pass the node name as a parameter of "other_job" instead of putting a hard coded value

Comment: If you don't want to use hard coded value in your 'other_job', then you can use [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin). It still requires some pre-configuration of 'other_job', but without using `Restrict where this project can be run` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of biruk1230, here is a full solution :

```
import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import java.util.concurrent.*
import hudson.AbortException
import org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.*

def currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
current_node = currentBuild.getBuiltOn().getNodeName()

def j = Hudson.instance.getJob('MyJobName')
try {
  def params = [
    new NodeParameterValue('node', current_node, current_node),
  ]
  def future = j.scheduleBuild2(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction(params))
  println "Waiting for the completion of " + j.getName()
  anotherBuild = future.get()
} catch (CancellationException x) {
  throw new AbortException("aborted.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check `Restrict where this project can be run` option in 'other_job' configuration - you must specify the same node name there.
Then, this should work:

```
import hudson.model.*
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('other_job')
job.scheduleBuild();
```

If you don't want to use this option in your 'other_job', then you can use [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) (which you already used) and pass the NodeLabel parameter to downstream job.
In this case, see example from [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) page how to start another job with parameters (you need to use `NodeParameterValue` instead of `StringParameterValue`):

```
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('MyJobName')
def anotherBuild
try {
    def params = [
      new StringParameterValue('FOO', foo),
    ]
    def future = job.scheduleBuild2(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction(params))
    println "Waiting for the completion of " + HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + job.url, job.fullDisplayName)
    anotherBuild = future.get()
} catch (CancellationException x) {
    throw new AbortException("${job.fullDisplayName} aborted.")
}
println HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + anotherBuild.url, anotherBuild.fullDisplayName) + " completed. Result was " + anotherBuild.result
```

If it's not working, probably the issue is with node restrictions (e.g., there is only one executor for the node).

NOTE: I prefer to use [Jenkins pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) for job configurations. It allows you to store your build configs in [Jenkinsfiles](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) which can be loaded from repository (e.g., from GitLab). See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806918/10721592) of triggering job with `NodeParameterValue`.