# Trigger a job within a jenkins pipeline step in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a below pipeline job.
http://abc:8080/job/US/job/UK/job/UAT/job/DEVOPS/job/Testing/job/test-readcsv/configure

Within the groovy script of above job I need to trigger the below job.
http://abc:8080/job/US/job/UK/job/UAT/job/DEVOPS/job/Release/job/1.5.5.11-Release/configure
Can someone please help in triggering the job.

I am using below command but it gets failed with error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among step

echo "Triggering job for branch ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"

build job: "../../Release/1.5.5.11-Release", wait: false , parameters: [string(${csvContent}) , string(${params.param1}), string(${params.param2})]

Comment: Did you try it with `/job` too? "../../Release/job/1.5.5.11-Release"

Comment: Hope this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833277/trigger-jenkins-job-on-same-node-than-parent-with-groovy/53922333#53922333

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I do it in one of my Jenkins files. That error you're seeing is possibly because your parameters are not in double quotes.

```
    stage('Trigger Pipeline'){
      steps {
          script {
                 build job:'Path/to/job' , parameters:[
                 string(name: "param1",  value: "${params.foo}"),
                 string(name: "param2",  value: "${params.bar}"),
               ]
            } 
      }
    }
```