# Failure to trigger freestyle job from declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline job that is required to trigger a downstream freestyle job. I do that using this snippet:

```
build job: 'DL_TVG_Backward_Compatibility_Verification', 
    parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'CHECK_CAM2', value: true), 
                    [$class: 'ListSubversionTagsParameterValue', 
                        name: 'CAM2_GOLDEN_TAG', tag: '', 
                        tagsDir: '<snip>/tags'], 
                    string(name: 'CAM2_SCENARIOS', value: ''), 
                    booleanParam(name: 'CHECK_CAM3', value: false), 
                    <snip>
                    [$class: 'NodeParameterValue', 
                        name: 'UPSTREAM_NODE', 
                        labels: ['jenkinswin10'], 
                        nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']], 
                    string(name: 'EMAIL_RECIPIENTS', 
                            value: '<snip>')
                ]
```

The downstream job fails:

```
[Pipeline] build (Building DL_TVG_Backward_Compatibility_Verification)
Scheduling project: DL_TVG_Backward_Compatibility_Verification
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Failed to trigger build of DL_TVG_Backward_Compatibility_Verification
Finished: FAILURE
```

Unfortunately no reason for the failure is given.  Is there a way to get more information about the reason?

I am unsure about the line:

```
                    [$class: 'NodeParameterValue', 
                        name: 'UPSTREAM_NODE', 
                        labels: ['jenkinswin10'], 
                        nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']],
```

Maybe that is wrong.

Any idea why this snippet fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you check the jenkins log for errors? Looks like the Backward-Job was found by Jenkins (Consolen-Log: "Scheduling...").
2. Do you have a Node-Parameter UPSTREAM_NODE in your Downstream-Job deklared? Check: [How to trigger a jenkins build on specific node using pipeline plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin)
3. Syntax of your NodeParameterValue in the build-Step looks fine. Check: [How to use a parameter from NodeLabelParameter Plugin with the "build" step of Jenkins Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794804/how-to-use-a-parameter-from-nodelabelparameter-plugin-with-the-build-step-of-j/29806918)
4. Did you checked the configuration of the label 'jenkinswin10'? Did you already executed builds successfully on one agent of the label?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad if i could help you :) Best regards