# How to pass NodeParameterValue as paramter in "build" pipeline step in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job that accepts NODE as parameter. I want to trigger the job from Jenkins pipeline using "build step" plugin. Passing the value as string is not working as the job is landing on random node

Here is my pipeline code. RepairAgentWorkspace expect NODE_TO_REPAIR to be a node type.

```
node{
     build job: 'RepairAgentWorkspace', 
     parameters: [string(name: 'NODE_TO_REPAIR', value: "git_agent")]
}
```

Above code triggers the job but it's not landing on "git_agent" agent. Any idea how can we pass node as param?

Comment: could you please at the relevant parts of the RepairAgentWorkspace code as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a parameter from NodeLabelParameter Plugin with the "build" step of Jenkins Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794804/how-to-use-a-parameter-from-nodelabelparameter-plugin-with-the-build-step-of-j)

Comment: @Sasha Will try. For now i made the parameter string and passing node label as string as workaround